# debug of an function

Tags: python, python-3.x

The "Faculty " function, should return the faculty of the number it receives as a parameter. The faculty of a number n is 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * ... * n. For example, faculty (5) should be 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120. The function as it is written now always returns 0, no matter what number it receives as a parameter.

So, how do I fix the problem? (I'm just trying to learn, I'm new)

```
def faculty(integer):
    result = 1
    for i in range(integer):
        result *= i
    return result
```

Comment: try ```range(1,interger+1)```

Comment: As you are computing faculty, I suggest also taking look at [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`range(stop)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) generates the values `[0;stop[` so you have the 0 which kill everything, and not `stop`.
What you need is `range(start, stop)` with `range(1, integer+1)` to generates `[1;value+1[`

```
def faculty(integer):
    result = 1
    for i in range(1, integer+1):
        result *= i
    return result
```

---

When debugging, a nice way is in most time to  use `print` to see what values are used to understand the behaviour of the code

Answer (score 2):

The range statement takes a 0 as starting point. Therefore, the result is directly set to 0. You could change it to:

```
def faculty(integer):
    result = 1
    for i in range(1, integer+1):
        result *= i
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider what values your loop is looping over.

```py
for i in range(integer):
    print(i)
```